# Android layout checkbox-text-right alligned button combination

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to achieve something that should be relatively simple but somehow android layout is just working on different wavelength from me and I can't get it done right.

I want to have a simple checkbox on the left a button on a right and a text filling the middle as needed with checkbox and button staying centered vertically if I have more than one line of text.

My layout and horrendous result are depicted below. Any ideas on how to achieve what I described would be much appreciated.

Thank you very much

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">


<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/chkEnabled" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/rowText"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnNavigate"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"

    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:text="Go"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:textSize="10sp" />

</LinearLayout >
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that use weight with linear layout

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

or you can use it relativelayout and give alignparentright true to button

```
 <LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/chkEnabled" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/rowText"
                android:text="this is test"
                android:layout_weight="1"

                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnNavigate"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"

                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:text="Go"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

        </LinearLayout >
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: glad to help you..happy coding

Answer (score 0):

if you want checkbox and button staying centered vertically than layout_gravity="center_vertical"

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="5"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/chkEnabled"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rowText"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="3.5"
    android:text="here is your text"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnNavigate"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Go"
    android:textSize="10sp"/>
```